# Array function to image list

Tags: php

I'm using WordPress and advanced custom fields, and I want to display 3-6 images depending on which fields are selected on a Select field post type.

I have it so the value/variables tie into the image name, so it would display images selected based on your choices.

e.g. "red : Red"

```
<img src="example.com/images/image-<?php the_field(color) ?>.jpg" alt="<?php the_field(color) ?>">
```

Now the noob question is, when more than one field is selected, it returns an array (i.e. red, green, black.) and I can't really have the function output as an array since it won't match the image name.

Does anyone know how to separate an array for multiple image outputs?

Comment: are you asking how to retrieve item from an array ?

Comment: Yes, but I would like all the items from the array to display separately into images based on the value name. So far I am using 

foreach ($image_list as $image) {
printf('<img src="/media/gems/64px-%s_gem_icon.png" alt="%s" />', $image['gem_selection_3'], $image['gem_selection_3']);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
foreach ($image_list as $image) {
    printf('<img src="example.com/images/image-%s.jpg" alt="%s" />', $image['color'], $image['color']);
}
```

If you don't have an associated array but just a simple array you might do:

```php
foreach ($gem_colors as $color) {
    printf('<img src="example.com/images/image-%s.jpg" alt="%s" />', $color, $color);
}
```

Comment: Still trying to figure this out, getting closer but getting a php error. Here is the website I'm implementing this one http://teambauce.com/test/

Comment: I have the custom field type as 'gem_selection_1', with the array showing the gem titles e.g. red, blue, green

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
<?php foreach($imageArray as $row): ?>
    <img src="example.com/images/image-<?php echo $row['color']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row['color']; ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```